# Can I overload Typescript generic types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, overloading

Say I have a function with some complicated types

```
function torgle<
    A extends string, 
    B extends number, 
    Flurg extends string = `[${A}]<>[${B}]`
>(flurg: Flurg): string {
    return `hello, ${String(flurg).replace(/[[\]<>]/g, '')}`
}
```

Normally I don't have a type `Flurg` already defined, and it's convenient to let `torgle` build it for me:

```
torgle<'blue', 32>('[blue]<>[32]')
hello, blue32
```

But sometimes I have a nonstandard `Flurg` type, and I want to make by own custom version and pass that in:

```
>> torgle<'_unused', '_unused', 'cheeseburger'>('cheeseburger')
hello, cheeseburger
```

But now `A` and `B` don't do anything and just get in the way. Obviously I'd rather just have a different version of `torgle` where they're not required:

```
function torgle<Flurg extends string>(flurg: Flurg) { ... }
```

See [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-y98iu7).

So, is there some way to overload these two `torgle` methods, or do I need a `torgle1` and `torgle2`?

Comment: Manually passing type arguments to function is a bit of a weird use case (usually you'd like inference from inputs) and I'm kind of disturbed by what your function is doing and how it's only tangentially related to the types in your call signatures (if I call `torgle("w<h]a[t>?")` I'm not sure how to interpret that in the context of `A`, `B`, or  `Flurg`).  But anyway if you're just trying to overload the `torgle` function, why not... overload the `torgle` function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w22dbw)? If that works for you I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: normally its good always do a data normalization, because if you have multiple dirty data formats it can break your code in long term, your code work, its good, but it can generate a "code smell"

Comment: @jcalz I may have failed here trying to boil down my complicated real-world case, which doesn't look much like this, into a minimal example. I've updated the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-y98iu7?file=/index.ts) with a more realistic (though still simplified) version of what I'm trying to do where the return type isn't just `string`. Please let me know if that helps clarify. (Still working on mapping your proposed solution onto mine.)

Comment: Like [this maybe](https://tsplay.dev/we8lVW)?  If you're overloading you need to make sure the overloads are distinguishable; if you have two ways to call `wrangle<T>(arg)` with a single type argument, then the compiler will pick one depending on order and applicability.  You should come up with a well-defined [mre] with clearly laid out success criteria, then [edit] your question to include it (as plaintext and not just an external IDE link), and then hopefully I (or someone else?) will be able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Typescript you can create [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) with strings, so its possible do this

```
type Flurg = `[${string}]<>[${number}]` | string;
function torgle(flurg: Flurg): string {
  return `hello, ${String(flurg).replace(/[[\]<>]/g, '')}`
}
console.log(torgle('[blue]<>[32]')); // hello, blue32
console.log(torgle('cheeseburger')); // hello, cheeseburger
```

and it removes Generics from your code(Generics a little more difficult to understand at frist aproach)

Comment: In what sense is this different from `type Flurg = string`? Actually if you inspect with IntelliSense it just says `type Flurg = string`.  So this answer doesn't actually involve template literal types in a relevant way. 